# Aliasing the Module in Google-API-client Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-api-client

1. Summarize the problem:

   - Being relatively new to Ruby/Gems and developing in general, some concepts evade me
   - I'm learning about the google-api-client Gem, and am attempting to understand the Basic Usage, and want to know how a developer knows which class to use, when instantiating an ojbect, during the "aliasing of the module" portion:

> To use an API, include the corresponding generated file and instantiate the service. For example to use the Drive API:

```rb
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2 # Alias the module
drive = Drive::DriveService.new # why is ::DriveService used here?
#etc
```

2. Describe what I've tried:

   - I've searched through the reference documentation for the [google-api-client](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/index.html) for a clue about the "decision" to instantiate `drive` with `::DriveService.new`
   - The best reason I've come up with is: `DriveService` is instantiated because it is the "BaseService" of the "DriveV2" Class.... but I'm reaching for straws with this logic.

My specific question is:

#### How does a developer using APIs and this Google-API-client Gem know which object to instantiate?

I have to imagine there's a more elegant "way" to determine which object to instantiate at this point of accessing an API than digging through the documentation of the Gem....I mean...the "BaseService" information is coming from the documentation for this specific Gem.....

Maybe this is a matter of me losing "scope" per say by the Google API and the ambiguously named Gem maintained by Google...

But then again...if I'm using this Gem...then this documentation would always apply, because I wouldn't be able to use this Gem if it wasn't a Google-API....

Answer (score 0):

[from the documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client#authorization-using-api-keys)

The link above is the necessary detail regarding Authorization for an API key.

If you're like me, and this subject is new to you, there are three topics that you need to understand:

1. Authentication
2. Authorization
3. Accounting

The documentation for the google-api-client gem is robust enough to answer a lot of questions, however, my answer here is hopefully enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

I'm leaving the question up, in case anyone else needs some guidance regarding this same subject.